# InternetReadFile returns text with extra characters at the end

Tags: c++, c, ftp, wininet

```
HINTERNET hInternet, hFtpSession, hFile;

    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, FTPHOST, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
        FTPUSER, FTPPASS, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
    hFile = FtpOpenFile(hFtpSession, argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0);

    DWORD rSize;
    char tmp[2048];
    string buffer;

    while(InternetReadFile(hFile, tmp, 2048, &rSize) && rSize > 0)
    {
        buffer += (string)tmp;
    }

    cout << buffer;

    InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
```

I have this small program to read a text file from an FTP server to a string, but in the end of the read string there are some extra characters. I guess the problem is with the size of the text but I can't figure it out.

For example I want to download an encrypted text it will be corrupted like this

```
MIICIDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg0AMIICCAKCAgEAp2q+92EQPncY0sN6SMTC0yh05GpZ
FUEGATvUx/zcUrzdDTva5JKz0MztuCn3lnHmaUB6L97w8fuVOhJjj90ItH4FdUk4R9m50son
DSZ4ad5ZKi7WE7GApIq21vgM0zoG5sr0Xb6X41IQgvYF7i9nX4zKO2znRyD3uzBqkqkhWzbS
HI2euCdhmXfx2az0ynNKrcnQINaWowipc0LrW0Q9PWI1McCs4V5sz8GkBMpKENb3m/LBlSqz
TboC/9hiD9Yfclvk3wFeNGvsnUUDpwZipF9cBMVzmfyjA1gBDNLV8qcTXSortHaGeHdLpqIg
Qn3SpDol8gPRis7A7Hy4KjRS8Y/iZa8Nv9EmEeful6u3IHY0Qror/wOeST5WhaTynVBT0wgP
6GSMWsofwA3NttsFCw55z5c8GBEGP6Uo+jP/rdiYvednT0iV8Grp+XJ6zMFqYlVcLqAzQWLw
dfqve/lr8+OKfR9WvG6hvrVduTnoy+LBFF/QEVxAlZqymlXMm/hcO/TUoE1Kmon6FwID4Mek
nV1eb1aCmUIzxFHtPkMO0KFitmxa5EGwAFHRAjXrp2lUHIQSaWwVnsfoQgmrG9ux2I27w+WR
8kFdkqWrutFz2xn6ovVwla7Oj0iL2f9azNO2Z2KT/sBPwGmI67M9Ceih0YLD0w7Woy32H2aM
mIeK368CARE=
8
```

The 8 shouldn't be there at the end.

Comment: `string` is not a C type.  Please, don't tag this question as `C`.  Also, you cannot overload operators in C (like `buffer += ...`)  This question has nothing to do with C.  Please, edit the question and take the `C` tag off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function InternetReadFile doesn't null terminate the buffer, so the content of the array tmp is not a string, yet you treat it as such.

The behavior is undefined.

Remove this line:

```
buffer += (string)tmp;
```

Instead use the overload of the string function append, which takes an array and it's size:

```
buffer.append( tmp , rSize );
```

Comment: I see, but then how can I cast the buffer to a string or what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

As 2501 said you aren't taking into account the NULL terminator, so what you would want to do would be something like this

```
DWORD rSize;
char tmp[2048+1];
string buffer;

while(InternetReadFile(hFile, tmp, 2048, &rSize) && rSize > 0)
{
    tmp[rSize] = '\0';
    buffer += (string)tmp;
}
```